# Python : Can anyone tell me why this while loop is freezing?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to get this homework done for class and no matter what I do, it freezes at the while loop. Everything seems correct to me but I am also pretty new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
print("This program will tell you how long it will take you to retire.")

yearlyReturns = float(input("Enter your yearly investment returns (est .05): "))

monthlyWithdraw = float(input("Enter percentage of your savings you will withdraw monthly (est .04): "))

income = float(input("Enter your monthly income: "))

percentSavings = float(input("Enter the percent of your income you save per month: "))

monthlySavings = (income * percentSavings)

expenses = (income - monthlySavings)

expensesTotal = (expenses * 12)

yearlyReturns = (yearlyReturns / 12)

totalAmount = (yearlyReturns * monthlySavings)

retire = (totalAmount * monthlyWithdraw)
months = 0
while retire < expenses:

    totalAmount = (totalAmount + monthlySavings)

    totalAmount = (totalAmount * yearlyReturns)

    months = months + 1

years = (months / 12)
print(income)

print(expenses)

print(monthlySavings)

print("It took ",months," to save enough to retire.")

print("That will be ",years," years.")

print("See what saving a little bit more would do.")
```

Comment: You don't change 'retire' or 'expenses' inside your while loop, so it will run for ever.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not changing `retire` or `expenses` in the loop, so once you enter the loop, you never leave.

Move the statement `retire = totalAmount * monthlyWidthdraw` into the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of retire or expenses within the body of the loop.